# How do I define map and fold on search trees?

Tags: search, haskell, tree, higher-order-functions

I have a search tree that's defined as:

```
data (Ord a) => Stree a = Null | Fork (Stree a) a (Stree a) deriving Show
```

and I have to define two functions, mapStree:

```
mapStree :: (Ord b, Ord a) => (a -> b) -> Stree a -> Stree b
```

and foldStree:

```
foldStree :: (Ord a) => (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> Stree a -> b
```

I don't fully understand what's going on and don't know how to do this.

Comment: (Off-topic). GHC can automatically derive Functor and Foldable to define the above two functions (provided that the `Ord a =>` constraint does not exist).

Comment: It is not clear what the role of Ord is.  I presume the tree is to be ordered by the Ord instance, left to right.  In that case, is 'mapStree' allowed to assume that its function is monotone (ie, preserves the order) or does mapStree need to re-sort as it goes?

Comment: Most of what the professor talks about is not clear, I'm not even sure he knows what Ord does himself as he cant explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your map to apply a function to any label carried by your tree. This means that any occurrence of `a` is to be changed to an occurrence to `b`, using the function given as a transformation function.

To do this, you'll need to figure out what to do with each possible constructor of the `Stree`. Now, `Null` is easy -- it won't depend on `a` in the first place. Trickier is what to do with `Fork`. In `Fork`, there is one `a`, and two further `Stree`s sitting around, so you need functions that take `a -> b` and that take `Stree a -> Stree b`. For the former, the invocation of `mapStree` gives you a function, and for the latter, `mapStree f` has the call signature you need (by partial application!).

For `foldStree`, you have some accumulation type `b` and your labeltype `a`, and an accumulation function that takes two values of type `b` and a value of type `a` and produces a `b`. This is helpful, not in the least because that accumulation function mirrors what you might have at any given `Fork` in the tree: by recursion you can assume you have results from both left and right `Stree`, and it only remains to combine those with the `a` value you have in the middle to give a new `b` value to hand up the recursion. The `b` parameter to `foldStree` provides you with enough of a standard value to get the whole thing started by getting a value for each leaf.

Thus, your `foldStree` will also need to be defined on the possible constructors: picking out the parameter for a `Null` value, and then for a `Fork` value, it needs to recurse into both `Stree` values before combining everything with the parameter combining function.

Please clarify in comments whether this helps you enough to deal with the problem: I (and many others here) can clarify, but the hope is for you to learn how to do it rather than to just hand you code.

Comment: Your second attempt at `mapStree f (Fork left x right)` looks good: you'll want to apply `mapStree f` to both `left` and `right`, and you'll want to apply `f` to `x`.

Comment: @a.d. `f(x)` in your attempts there isn't doing what you think it is - it will pass f and y as successive arguments to Fork, which will cause a type error.  Looks like you understand function application syntax, since you got (mapStree f xt) and (mapStree f yt) right, so I'm guessing that's probably just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Lecture 5 from [this course](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures.html).